# MySQL table with 4,000,000 record?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, geospatial

The website I have to manage is a search engine for worker (yellow page style)

I have created a database like this:

```
People: <---- 4,000,000 records
id
name
address
id_activity <--- linked to the activites table
tel
fax
id_region <--- linked to the regions table

activites: <---- 1500 activites
id
name_activity

regions: <--- 95 regions
id
region_name

locations: <---- 4,000,000 records
id_people
lat
lon
```

So basically the request that I am having slow problem with is to select all the "workers" around a selecty city (select by the user)

The request I have created is fully working but takes 5-6 seconds to return results...

Basically I do a select on the table locations to select all the city in a certain radius and then join to the people table

```
  SELECT people.*,id, lat, lng, poi,  
         (6371 * acos(cos(radians(plat)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians(plon)) + sin(radians(plat)) * sin(radians(lat)))) AS distance 
    FROM locations,
         people 
   WHERE locations.id = people.id 
  HAVING distance < dist 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

My questions are:

1. Is my Database nicely designed? I don't know if it's a good idea to have 2 table with 4,000,000 records each. Is it OK to do a select on it?
2. Is my request badly designed?
3. How can I speed up the search?

Comment: Your SQL has a `HAVING` clause but no `GROUP BY` - are you sure this is right?

Comment: Does each person have eaxactly 1 locaion or can each person have many locations? Moving the lat+lng table into the people table will help if there is no other reason for them to be split.

Comment: @Oded: Yes i have the group just forgot to cupy paste

Comment: Show the results of `explain` just in case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The design looks normalized. This is what I would expect to see in most well designed databases. The amount of data in the tables is important, but secondary. **However** if there is a 1-to-1 correlation between `People` and `Locations`, as appears from your query, I would say the tables *should* be one table. This will *certainly* help.
2. Your SQL looks OK, though adding constraints to reduce the number of rows involved would help.
3. You need to [index your tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html). This is what will normally help most with slowness (as most developers don't consider database indexes at all).

Comment: Just one more suggestion (or something to consider possibly later on). If your database has several other tables, with several other rows and you are still noticing some performance issues, SQL Server has a feature called 'FILE GROUPS'. FILE GROUPS allows you to set different databases, and even groups of tables to use a different directory. This has some great performance benefits when using multiple hard drives. I don't know, however, if MySQL has a 'FILE GROUPS' equivalent.

Comment: Yes it's a 1-1, beacause each people has his one location. SO Ok I will try to put it in the same table.
And I will see for the indexes.

But even tough all that, I don't know if it will help much. I will see. Because when i look at the http://www.yellowpages.com/ for example. Which i think got more than 4 000 000 clients... it takes not even 1 secondes to show the results

Comment: So, i have deleted my table location and put the lon and lat in the people table I try to put an index on the field long ang lat, but the query still take 4-5 seconds to complete

Comment: @Fazoulette - You are retrieving 4,000,000 records - the time to transfer that much data is easily accounted for by 4-5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of basic things that could be making your query run slowly.

What are your indexes like on your tables? Have you declared primary keys on the tables? Joining two tables each with 4M rows without having indexes causes a lot of work on the DB. Make sure you get this right first.

If you've already built the right indexes for your DB you can look at caching data. You're doing a calculation in your query Are the locations (lat/lon) generally fixed? How often do they change? Are the items in your locations table actual places (cities, buildings, etc), or are they records of where the people have been (like Foursquare checkins)?

If your locations are places you can make a lot of nice optimizations if you isolate the parts of your data that change infrequently and pre-calculate the distances between them.

If all else fails, make sure your database server has enough RAM. If the server can keep your data in memory it will speed things up a lot.

Comment: 1: Ok i have wrong here i don't uses indexes
2: the locations table is the lon lat of places (a pizzeria for example) so it's fixed

3: Not sure to see what you mean. Like for a specifique city pre-calulcate all the pizzeria around that city ?

Comment: On the scale of pizzarias, not so much. That sounds more like location-aware computing (like Foursquare).

If your locations are within a small area you might be able to approximate distances using the Pythagorean theorem instead of your trigonometry-heavy calculation.